# Design of low pass filter

Tags: filters, lowpass-filter, phase

I'm designing a low pass filter to identify the DC content of a signal. The most important aspects of my application are the accuracy and the speed of the identification.

I would like to know if the phase lag brought by the filter plays an important role in my problem, because I have developped a filter that has a great performance in time (it identifies the DC component very fast and accurately), but its frequency response is poor in terms of phase. Do I really need to worry about it in this situation?

Comment: "**I'm designing a low pass filter to identify the DC content of a signal.**" .... "**but its frequency response is poor in terms of phase.**" --- why would the frequency response at any frequencies other than those close to DC be of any salience?

Comment: Right. So if my filter has a cut-off frequency of 10 Hz (the AC part of the signal has very high frequency), there is no problem in having a phase of -128° at this frequency?

Comment: @ViníciusLopesSimões how are *we* supposed to know that? Do you *care* about the signal at 10 Hz?

Comment: Not at all! Thank you!